# Motivation for $\gamma$-operations in K-Theory / Lambda rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, topological-k-theory, lambda-rings

I'm struggling to understand the motivation for the $\gamma$-operations in the context of $\lambda$-rings, with specific application to topological $K$-theory.

Given a $\lambda$-ring, $R$, the $\lambda$-operations have the property that $\lambda_t(x)$ is a polynomial of order $dim(x)$. The augmentation ideal $I$ does not contain many finite dimensional elements, so we define the $\gamma$-operations which have the property that $\gamma_t(x)$ is polynomial on $I$.

There then seem to be two main results to follow from this:

1) We prove that the operations on $\gamma$-rings are $\mathbb{Z}[\gamma_1, \dots]^+$, or that $Op(K_1, K) = \mathbb{Z}[[\gamma_1, \dots]]$.

2) We can discuss the $\gamma$-filtration and it's properties.

I don't fully understand the need for the $\gamma$-operations, they are just a linear combination of the $\lambda$-operations. Why do we choose to work with them? Moreover, why can we not talk about a $\lambda$-filtration defined in similar way and work with this instead?

My references I've been working from are Atiyah's $K$-theory and Yau's Lambda-rings.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: «Why can't we talk about the $\lambda$-filtration defined in a similar way and work with this instead?» Simply because it does not work. The $\gamma$-filtration was constructed to do something: you cannot do the same thing with the other one.ç

Comment: In which case I guess my question is, exactly what was the $\gamma$-filtration constructed to do, and why would the $\lambda$-operation achieve this?